# Create Sequence Diagram Using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, uml

I would like to create sequence diagram with data of reading text file.
Moreover I want to output that diagram in Excel.
Using Language is Excel VBA.
What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would split the task in the following steps:

1. Create/read/extract the data of the activities to be shown in the diagram
2. Convert the data into a suitable format
3. Translate the data into an image (`.gif` or `.jpg` format)
4. Import the image into the `Excel` file

Step 1 depends on the source and structure of your data.

Steps 2.+3. are determined by the tool of your choice to generate the actual diagram. You could use something like [sdedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sdedit). Use the `VBA shell` command to call such an external tool from within your `VBA` code. Online services like [https://www.websequencediagrams.com](https://www.websequencediagrams.com/) are probably difficult to integrate in a local tool.

Importing a picture in `Excel` can either be done directly (menu `Insert`) or via an `Image` control in a `user form`.

Tools like [TextUML](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/textuml/index.php?title=TextUML_Toolkit) internally call [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to create the diagrams. You could do the same and use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for step 3 in my list above.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Axel Kemper.But I don't want to use Tools.So, could I develop only VBA code to generate Sequence Diagram and import Excel?

Comment: Have a look at the tools mentioned and make up you mind. I doubt that it would make much sense.